# How to prevent Gmail from creating map link from address?

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

When Gmail detects an address within the text of an email, it automatically converts that address into a link to Google Maps.

(I think this "feature" must be new because it hadn't happened in the past.)

I'm using Active Campaign to send emails to prospective clients, and the footer of the email contains a mailing address (which I think is required due to spam laws).

Gmail users who receive my emails see the mailing address in the footer as a blue hyperlink, which distracts from the main content of my emails.

I already know about [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988534/prevent-gmail-to-create-link-for-url-and-email) for preventing Gmail from converting email addresses into links.

**How can I ensure that Gmail doesn't mess with the formatting of my mailing address text?**

I just want it to be gray text (and not link to anything).

Comment: I tried wrapping the address in `<code></code>` or `<kbd></kbd>` HTML tags, but those didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following approach seems to work!

`<a href="" style="text-decoration:none;color: rgba(227,227,227,0.5);">%SENDER-INFO-SINGLELINE%</a>`

Basically, I'm now preemptively making the address into a link, but it's a link to nowhere (`href=""`), and its underlining is removed (`text-decoration:none;`).

I adapted an answer I found [here from Abby Wentzel](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/321-how-to-prevent-gmail-from-changing-font-color-for-phone-numbers-address-dates#comment-1613).

Comment: I'm curious to hear whether my question and answer here helps anyone else.

Comment: Works for me in Gmail. I used "#" instead of "".

Comment: It works for me too.

Comment: This was so clever.  Worked like a charm!

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/233434/excrispy recommends adding `pointer-events: none;` to the style to remove the hand cursor (at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/136671/27487 ). Adding `cursor: pointer;` is another idea.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `<a>` tag Ryan provided works, a basic `<span>` tag seems to work as well in the emails I tested.

Comment: I test with <span>address</span> and it is not working for me